# A lot of Theme APIs stop working in Liferay 6.1 while these APIs working in 6.0 and 5.2

Tags: api, liferay-6, liferay-velocity, liferay-theme

I have a serious issue with Liferay 6.1 themes , I know well about themes in Liferay and theme developer, i was working in Liferay 5.2 and 6.0 with the same way, the same APIs and Calls that written in :

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CMS+Internal+API#section-CMS+Internal+API-Backend+Journal+Service+Calls

and

http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Access+Objects+from+Velocity#section-Access+Objects+from+Velocity-Themes

and another wikis,

for test : like the following link code not working in 6.1 but working in 6.0 and 5.2 :

```
http://localhost:8080/c/journal/get_articles?delta=10
```

you can refer to : http://www.liferay.com/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/journal-vm-template-meets-saxreaderutil

**What I want**: Any idea about how at least getting articles while `/c/journal/get_articles` not working anymore!

Second: where I can find helpful "content" in theme of liferay 6.1 !

Note:
I tested that in Liferay 6.1 EE and CE and on more than one machine, and I have same issue !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the problem that I got earlier. I went in \liferay-portal-src-6.1.0-ce-ga1\portal-impl\src\com\liferay\portlet\journal\action\GetArticlesAction.java & saw that "type" parameter is required. so now my get_articles link looks like this & is working:
http://@portal_url@/c/journal/get_articles?groupId=@group_id@&templateId=$templateID&type=Blogs
so Blogs is an example. by default when creating a new article you have General type(in Categorization)